# Convert scientific notation to nano OR microsecond format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The intention is to convert the below scientific notation to human readable format.

```
"Time": 2e-8 => 20 ns (nano second)
"Time": 1e-8 => 10 ns
"Time": 3e-9 => 3 ns
"Time": 5e-7 => 300 ns
"Time": 3.0000000000000007e-8 => 30 ns
```

There is another requirement to convert in to micro second where applicable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something, like that?

```js
const test = [5e-7, 1e-2, 3e-12, 5e-10, 3.0000000000000007e-8],

      convert = n => {
        const suffixes = ['ms', 'us', 'ns', 'ps'],
              {log,min,floor} = Math,
              range = -1*floor(log(n)/log(10)/3),
              base = 0|n*10**(3*min(range,suffixes.length))
        return `${base}${suffixes[min(range,suffixes.length)-1]}`         
      }
      
 console.log(test.map(convert))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function convertTime(time) {
    return Math.round(time * (10 ** 9)) + ' ns';
}

console.log(convert(2e-8))                  // 20 ns
console.log(convert(1e-8))                  // 10 ns
console.log(convert(3e-9))                  // 3 ns
console.log(convert(5e-7))                  // 500 ns
console.log(convert(3.0000000000000007e-8)) // 30 ns
```